# Setting global variable for mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

As I am working my SQL, for example if I have

```
select
concat(author_fname, ' ', author_lname)..
....
from...
```

The question that I have is when I do multiple queries, I have to type that concat command over and over again.

Is there a way that I can set a global variable let's say

```
set
@full_name =(
    select
        concat(author_fname, ' ', 
        author_lname)
    from
        books
);
```

Now I only need to do:

```
select full_name 
from books;
```

But my set command does not work, I don't think declare is the way to go, is there a way to tackle this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: This is possible - if all queries are executed in the same connection, and this connection is not closed/failed/dropped. UDV is local within the connection - so its change or reconnect will clear it (more precisely, new connection will have its own empty variable with this name).

Comment: But it's better to use SELECT .. INTO instead of SET.

Comment: You can only set a variable to a single value, not all the names in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view:

```
create view v_books as
    select concat(author_fname, ' ', author_lname) as full_name, b.*
    from books b;
```

You will see the column if you select from the view.

Or use a generated column if you want it when selecting directly from the table:

```
alter table books add full_name varchar(255) generated always as
    (concat(author_fname, ' ', author_lname));
```

Comment: strange that I did not think of creating a new column, thank you again for your help!